# magento SOAP "Unknown Content-Encoding"

Tags: magento, soap

I try to use magento SOAP but i get the error "SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unknown Content-Encoding"
the code i use is this:

```
function init_connector() {
global $mage_url,$mage_user, $mage_api_key, $sessionId, $proxy;

try {

 $proxy = new SoapClient( $mage_url ."/api/?wsdl" ); //calling this function with no errors
 // Login to Magento
 $sessionId = $proxy->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key ); //this call trigers the exception
 return 1;
 } catch( SoapFault $fault ) {
    logError($fault);
    return 0;
 }
}
```

when creating the object $proxy  i get no errors, but when i call $sessionId = $proxy->login(...) i get the above exception.

The same code works fine for other magento installations.

Are there any suggestions?
Thanks..

Comment: Best guess, might be related with your server. Did you use apache deflate, header extensions? ( Or maybe you didn't use apache )

Comment: i also believe it's server related, but i don't know where to look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Oğuz.
I'm struggling 2 days now and finaly found the solution. I don't know why the server responds like this (although i would really like to know) but if i create SoapClient with this, it works.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient( $mage_url, array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));
```

testing the code (without option 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT) on another server which uses gzip compression didn't have that problem..

Answer (score 1):

Also, please try this and let share us result.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient($site_path.'api/soap/?wsdl=1');
```

Comment: no this didn't help either.. don't know if this help but from eclipse debuger i get this response. $http_response_header Array [8] 
 0 (string:15) HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 1 (string:35) Date: Fri, 16 Mar 2012 15:10:48 GMT 
 2 (string:14) Server: Apache 
 3 (string:22) **Content-Encoding: none** 
 4 (string:20) Content-Length: 9223 
 5 (string:16) Vary: User-Agent 
 6 (string:17) Connection: close 
 7 (string:37) Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 ##sorry can't format inside comments..##

Comment: check apache mod_deflate, mod_header extensions. if they are enabled, temporarily disable and try again pls.

Comment: also, check php.ini `output_handler = ob_gzhandler`, if this line enabled, temporarily disable it. PS : if you are on shared hosting provider, you can set by `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help somebody:

```
    $mode = array (
        'soap_version'  => 'SOAP_1_1', // use soap 1.1 client
        'keep_alive'    => true,
        'trace'         => 1,
        'encoding'      =>'UTF-8',
        'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
        'exceptions'    => true,
        'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create ( 
            array (
                'http' => array('header' => 'Content-Encoding: gzip'),
            )
        )
    );
```

`$client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl, $mode );`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this solves the issue? Thanks.